# how to access object in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I have a scenario... I made a class RequestAndResponse in asp.net In App_Code folder. I want to access this in Default.aspx page but i am getting a problem
Here is the code:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    RequestAndResponse request = new RequestAndResponse();

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox_query.Text.Trim()))
            {
                request.getParameter(txtbox_query.Text.Trim(), sourcePath,parameterValue);
                request.BeginInvokeService(InvokeCompleted);

                Response.Write(returnFromService);
            }
            else
            {
                // to do
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Response.Write(error.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public static void InvokeCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        returnFromService = request.EndInvokeService(result);
    }
```

Now the scenario i hv created a object 'request' and want to access in InvokeCompleted method but i want able to do it.
How will i do this??

Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field,method or property 'Default.request'

Answer (score 1):

`InvokeCompleted` method is static and cannot access instance variables. Ether make `InvokeCompleted` method an instance method (remove `static` keyword) or make `request` static. It makes sense that you convert `InvokeCompleted` to an instance method.